How to forbid direct imports from other packages in a Typescript monorepo?
Im using vite in my monorepo and I want to prohibit direct imports (without passing throgh the package name).
I have this structure
root
|---packages
|     |-------front
|     |-------utils
|
|---package.json

I whant to avoid that someone does this
//in front/main.ts
import { something } from "../utils/lib.ts

They need to do this instead
import { something } from "@repo/utils"

I am using vite. I tried the fs.allowed option, but it does not prevent me from doing this wrong import.
//it still allows for every import style
fs:{
  allowed: ["./src"],
}

